# how to get current react component name inside custom react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook

```
function myCustomHook() {
   const currentComponentName = //? 
   return `currentComponentName${customSuffix}`
}

function Sample() {
  const name = myCustomHook()
}

function Component2() {
  const name = myCustomHook()
}
```

is it possible to get the unique name of a component? or any other alternative for this use case?

Comment: Did any post solve your problem? Kindly give some feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getName = () => {
    const stack = new Error().stack;
    const lines = stack.split("\n");
    const line = lines[3];
    const match = line.match(/at (.*) \(/);
    const name = match[1];
    return name;
  };
```

I got it using copilot...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `useRef` can help to deal with your case https://medium.com/trabe/react-useref-hook-b6c9d39e2022